# How to convert Query to NamedQuery?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm failing to convert a simple `Query` to a `@NamedQuery`. Am I missing something in the following code?

```
//works fine
em.createQuery("FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name").setParameter("name", name).getResultList();

//throws exception
em.createQuery(Person.FIND_BY_ID).setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = BookingRequest.FIND_BY_ID,
        query = "FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name"
    )
})
class Person {
    public static final String FIND_BY_ID = "Person.findById";
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1703)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
em.createNamedQuery("query name") ...
```

Comment: Hmn, I have no `em.getNamedQuery()`..., I'm using `javax.persistence.EntityManager`

Comment: if you have import javax.persistence.EntityManager; you should can use it

Comment: I cannot see this in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html, I think getNamedQuery is only for the Hibernate Session.

Comment: It's `createNamedQuery(String name)` apparently. But it's `getNamedQuery` for the Hibernate specific variant.